# What are the requirements for a warlock patron in Forgotten Realms?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, forgotten-realms, lore

In D&D 5th edition's Forgotten Realms setting what ability is required for a creature to be able to grant a creature warlock powers?

Comment: Have you read the relevant sections in the PHB about what these patrons are/what they do? What exactly makes you think there *are* any requirements for Forgotten Realms outside of just being a god or god-like entity? Note: Forgotten Realms is, I believe, the assumed default setting for a lot of 5e material.

Comment: Separated: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79199/what-are-the-requirements-for-a-cleric-patron-in-forgotten-realms

Comment: Are you looking for what the rules say about the class or just what the lore says? (I see the lore tag, I'm just making sure you're not looking for a "there are no rules" answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are not currently any hard and fast rules for what makes a viable warlock patron. What we do know is that the following all qualify:

1. immensely powerful fey (Titania, Oberron, Hyrsam, the Queen of Air and Darkness, the Prince of Frost)
2. immensely powerful demons and devils (Baazka, Belaphoss, Eltab, Errtu, Gargauth, Lorcan, Malkzid, Wendonai)
3. immensely powerful old ones (Dendar the Night Serpant, Ghaunadaur, Kezef, Moander, Tyranthraxus, Zargon)
4. immensely powerful undead (no list available)

All of this information comes from the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide.

One of the important things to note is the 'immensely powerful' part of the description - these are all quasi-deities according to the Divine Rank scale in the DMG, and most if not all would be considered vestiges.

Comment: Some of these like Gargauth and Dendar seem to be more powerful than quasi-deities but quasi-deity or more powerful seems sensible.

Comment: @StevenStewart-Gallus Gargauth and Dendar are not, to the best of my knowledge, capable of granting clerics spells, which by the definitions found in the Divine Rank sidebar of the DMG (p 11), limits them to quasi-deity, regardless of how powerful they may or may not be.

Comment: Dendar is a primordial and primordials are the gods of Abeir (which is parallel to Toril.) Gargauth was an archdevil who was trapped on Toril and then ascended to demigod status while on Toril.

Comment: You may wish to update this answer following the release of *Xanathar's* (and possibly other works) to at least include the new categories of Patrons.