# What is the difference between a god and a non-god power in Forgotten Realms?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, forgotten-realms

What is the difference between a "god" and a non-god power in the Forgotten Realms?

I assume that a "god" can grant cleric spells and that a non-god power cannot.

I am assuming D&D 5th edition.

Comment: Have you reviewed the section about Forces and Philosophies in the DMG on page 13?   I am not sure yet about your question, but that section may provide a helpful view of what can empower divine spells and effects for clerics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Godhood is decided primarily based on power, which in turn is generally decided based on the number of worshipers the prospective deity has (paraphrased from DMG 5e, p 11 under Divine Rank).

That means that gods - both lesser and greater - grant spells to clerics as a defining trait. Not being able to grant spells to clerics makes immensely powerful beings quasi-dieties of some sort.